# java gwt multiselectionmodel disable blue

Tags: java, css, gwt, celltable

I'm using multiselectionmodel for a cell table. When clicking on a row it is changed to a blue format. Is it somehow possible to disable this? Probably in a .css file?

Comment: any chance of example codes..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the styling of a `CellTable` however you want by providing your own `CellTable.Resources` in the constructor.

Comment: would it also be possible by using: this.taskTable.getElement().getStyle(). 
but now I don't know what to set?